# Office proofing: Remove a language from the earlier selected languages list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language, proofing

At several office applications one can select the language per word / selected text / whole document. To do so one clicks on review - language - set proofing language.
A 'language' windows pops up, showing some default languages (well, probably more accurately 'earlier selected' languages) in a shortlist at the top of a scrolling list, and then many, many languages in that scrolling longlist.

In my shortlist I have 5 languages used earlier, one of which I will never use again. Hence I want to remove it from that shortlist.

My question is: How?

(Windows 10, Office Professional Plus 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Go to “File” → “Options” → “Language”.

You will find a list of proofing languages. 
Just select not used one and click “Remove”:

[image: Step by step reve shyrokyi]
Then restart Word.

Comment: By the way we are able to create a hand-made hotkey or a _mouse gesture_ for setting some particular proofing language for a selected text. I'm using Strokes Plus for it.

This one is for setting Ukrainian language:
`acSendAltDown()
acSendAltUp()
acDelay(50)
acSendKeys("0{DELAY 50}8{DELAY 50}{PGUP}u{DELAY 50}{ENTER}")

acMouseMove(gsx, gsy)`